Table partition after DD Cloning
I've got some questions about table partition after dd cloning a full disk. I have been cloning a full disk with a dual boot: Win + Ubuntu to an image. The disk contained the following partition:
WIN: MBR Partition + Primary + Recovery and Ubuntu: Root partition '/' + Swap partition (I know this is not neccesary) + EFI Partition
and indirectly the Table partition which as far as I read, it is located in the very first 512 bytes (correct me if wrong) and a backup at the end of the disk.
I have shrank the main partitions of both OS to the minimum size and the compressed size result from ~60GiB to ~23GiB.
Well, I could make the reverse operation (de-compress from the image to the disk) and everything seems to be working fine after fixing table partition with gdisk.
However, I've got some questions about using DD:

Does the table partition storage information about the unallocated space? I mean, If I only use 50GiB from a 250GiB disk (200 GiB unallocated), when I decompress the disk image on disk which are bigger than 50GiB and have a different size of the original one, will I be able to clone on those kind of disk?
Soon I will try this installing both os, but on different disk. Can I just copy an specific partition?
Build on 2nd point, can i restore an image which only contain a unique partition to a partition with different size and fix the information on table partition?

I hope you can clear me some doubts, best regards.


Partition table only describes allocated space, but when you use modern GPT partition table (instead of DOS partition table), you probably need to "repair" the secondary (backup) partition table at the end of the drive, this can be done with programs like fdisk

You can copy, but your OS will probably not boot when not setting up in the right way, I recommend to reinstall the OS

It's possible to copy a volume (filesystem) from any smaller partition to any bigger or equal sized partition. After copying, you can either decrease partition size or increase filesystem size. It's not recommended to copy a volume (filesystem) from a bigger partiton to a smaller partition without some manual adjustments. The recommended way for copying a volume from a bigger partition towards a smaller partition is to either decrease the volume size via filesystem mechanics or create a smaller new filesystem on the target smaller partition and manually copy all files from filesystem to filesystem.



Thanks for answering, things are going clear. Respecting the 3rd point, whats the result with table partition after decompressing an image which containt a volume partition?

If you decompress an image which contains a partition table onto the top block device (example: /dev/sda or /dev/nvme0) you'll overwrite the existing primary partition table, the secondary partition table (GPT) might also be overwritten, if the top block device is a large as the decompressed image, or when it's smaller. You should never decompress an image which contains a partition table onto a non top block device (example: /dev/sda1 or /dev/nvme0p1), that would be a serious error. If you just want to decompress a specific partition from the image, that's another question.

My question was focused on the end of your answer. My idea is to decompress an image into a partition. What happens if the source of the image (origin partition) was smaller than the destiny partition. I mean, I create an image from a partition which had 20GiB, the result is an image of 18GiB (I.E). So I just wonder what happens I decompress the image into a partition which is bigger (50GiB) than the origin. Also, I wonder what happens if there is a partition which follows the destiny partition. Does DD process could alterate it? Under the context that the target is a partition/volume.

Oh, if the source volume is smaller or at least equal in size than the destination partition, that's no problem. For example, if you decompress a 10GB volume into a 20GB partition, the 10GB volume (aka filesystem) will just use the first 10GB of the 20GB partition. Later you can use filesystem tools (each filesystem has different tools) to enlarge the filesystem (volume) to the extends of the partition. A partition table is just a reservation of space, you are not obliged to use all the reserved space. But you should never use more than the reserved space, or face fatal system crashes.

I have serious doubt about cloning a partition to an image. Whats the result of this ? Will it result in an image with the data from origin partition or will result in an image which containt the partition itself? UUID and other info that could exists?

Boundaries and info (size, type of partition) of partitions are only stored in the partition table. Partition table is usually not part of a volume image. UUID is part of a volume (filesystem) and not part of a partition table. I recommend to do a small try, to do an experiment for yourself. It's not that hard. There also exists a lot of documentation about this topic. Please take your time and study those. Old DOS/BIOS partition table, called MBR - modern UEFI partition table, called GPT

After doing some test, everything seems to be working fine. However, to prevent any issue with overwriting data, what do u think about wiping the destiny partition with zeros by using /dev/zero (Lets calle it partition). This process shouldn't take so much time and later I could ensure a clean restoration. ¿What do you think?
